# how do I turn off annoying Visual Studio popup

Tags: visual-studio

I'm editing iOS .swift using Visual Studio on Windows.
This works good except VS pops up these suggestions a lot and I have to hit Esc every time.

I disabled VS > Tools > Options > All Lang > Gen > Statement completion > Auto list.. and parameter..
but did not fix it.

[image]